# Returning from ShowDialog property null

Tags: c#, wpf

I have developed a LoadWindow to load in `InvoiceData` with properties such as `Customer` and `Vehicle`.
The window has a `Page` with a `DataGrid` with `ItemsSource=LoadedInvoices`. Selecting an item and pressing Load button saves the `SelectedItem` into the Window's `SelectedInvoice` property.

This works fine on the first use. However, whatever I do beforehand, I can't use the Load a second time because a nested Object within InvoiceData is set null, even when I choose the same InvoiceData to load.

The code looks weird as I even tried using deep copy constructors, because I had the feeling, that these objects were cleared with window close. However, the problem persists.

**-The first load:**

[image: First Load, LocalData is set]

**-The second load** (with copy constructors included):
[image: LocalData.Customer is not set even tho it should be]

As you can notice, the set `SelectedInvoiceData` has `Customer` set both times with the same Customer. However, on the second run it's not copied over.

EDIT: The Vehicle property is copied both times. It's only the Customer, that's failing. Added the LoadInvoiceSelected button Click handler:

```
private void LoadInvoiceSelected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    LoadWindow parent = (LoadWindow)Window.GetWindow(this);
    InvoiceData selected = (InvoiceData)InvoiceDataGrid.SelectedItem;
    parent.DialogResult = selected != null;
    parent.SelectedInvoiceData = selected;
    parent.Close();
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Oh my gosh. So the problem was that my `SelectedItem` in ComboBox was bound to the property TwoWay. So when I ran `LoadCustomers`, it filled the ComboBox with all the possible Customers from the Database. Which, nulled the `SelectedItem` on the ComboBox and also **NULLED** the property out.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried storing the data in "public static variables"? Static variables don't care about how many times you used them, and can be accessed any where

Comment: The problem is not with accessing a variable, but setting it. Using static would also mess up my PropertyChanged functions etc.